# Simplest way to export a data set out of OpenStreetMap's Overpass API

Tags: openstreetmap, export, overpass-api

I would like to create a web map showing just one type of point of interest. They are made available via the Overpass API and count up to only few thousands for the whole world.

I don't expect them to change at all, they will at most slowly increase in number (they represent some very expensive equipment).

According to all the above, I thought to export all of them manually, store them as a JSON file that gets shipped to the clients when they connect for the first time. In some months I will redo the procedure and update the data.

I was able to implement this scenario using a very small subset of data. Now I would like to export the whole data set. How should I do?

Comment: Are you creating the JSON manually? And how are you querying the data?

Comment: ATM I queried the overpass api via web asking JSON as output. But I'm open to all kind of alternatives

Comment: Can you paste the query you are using?

Comment: I cannot paste the actual query, but it is similar to this one, except the tag is different `[out:json][timeout:25];
(
  node["amenity"="hospital"]({{bbox}});
);
out body;
`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to export the whole dataset you have to remove the `{{bbox}}` parameter.

Imagine you were exporting waste transfer stations (which are not as common as hospitals).

The following query will export all waste transfer stations inside the `bbox`:

```
[out:json][timeout:60];
(
  node["amenity"="waste_transfer_station"]({{bbox}}); 
); 
out body;
```

However, if you remove the `bbox` it will return *all* the waste transfer stations:

```
[out:json][timeout:60];
(
  node["amenity"="waste_transfer_station"]; 
); 
out body;
```

Furthermore, if you wanted to automize this process you could use Python and `requests` to get the data programatically. Feel free to ask another question if that is the case and I will gladly answer it.

Comment: I would highly recommend to check the number of objects via http://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/ before running this sort of query. Anything above a few thousand objects will most likely create too much load on the public instances. If you see more than say 50k entries, you should definitely use a bounding box, or if you still need the whole planet, download a planet file from planet.openstreetmap.org instead.

Comment: @mmd Yeah, you are right. Although he said it has only a few thousand objects. An alternative could be dividing the planet into quadrants and making a query for each quadrant, waiting a couple minutes in between each query.